# Dynamic creation of a Pydantic model with a `conint` field

Tags: python, pydantic

I have two models and want reduce it to one:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, conint


class Apples(BaseModel):
    count: conint(le=50, gt=0)


class Bananas(BaseModel):
    count: conint(le=100, gt=0)
```

The only difference is the max value of `count`.
`create_model` should be the solution:

```py
from pydantic import conint, create_model


def fruits_model_factory(max_count=200):
    return create_model('Fruit', count=conint(gt=0, lt=max_count))
```

but

```py
apple = fruits_model_factory(max_count=50)
my_apple = apple(count=66) # <----???? no validation error...
print(my_apple.count)  # <class 'ConstrainedIntValue'>
print(my_apple.dict())  # {}
```

Why?

Comment: `create_model('Fruit', count=(conint(gt=0, lt=max_count), ...))`

Comment: To elaborate a bit on the comment by @python_user: [_"Fields are defined by either a tuple of the form `(<type>, <default value>)` or just a default value."_](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/models/#dynamic-model-creation) But [constrained types](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/types/#constrained-types) are... well.. **types**. Therefore you must pass them in the form of a tuple.